# KMM: Unable to generate classes in iOS for the implementation of sealed interfaces inside sub-modules of shared code

Tags: android, ios, kotlin-multiplatform

This is how my project looks:
[image]

I have divided the shared part in to small modules as core, features and shared. The Shared module contains only koin implementation, coroutines adapter for iOS and build.gradle.kts where I have added the sub-modules as apis to consumed by both iOS and android.

This is working well on Android but in iOS the generated file doesn't contains the classes implementing sealed Interfaces in sub-module i.e. features.

[image]
[image]

As you can see above that it generates @protocol for the `Intent -> SharedSXLIntent` but not @class is generated for `GetAllLaunches`.

This is bit strange as this is working as expected when I added sealed interface and its implementation in the shared module it self.
[image]
[image]

Following is my `kmm/shared/build.gradle.kts` file
`

```
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.multiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.android.library)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.serialization)
}

kotlin {
    android()
    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach {
        it.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "shared"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(libs.kotlinx.datetime)
                implementation(libs.kotlinx.coroutines.core)
                api(project(":kmm:features:spaceXLaunches"))
                api(project(":kmm:core:common"))
                api(libs.koin.core)
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel)
            }
        }
        val androidTest by getting
        val iosX64Main by getting
        val iosArm64Main by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Main by getting
        val iosMain by creating {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            iosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
            dependencies {

            }
        }
        val iosX64Test by getting
        val iosArm64Test by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Test by getting
        val iosTest by creating {
            dependsOn(commonTest)
            iosX64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
        }
    }
}

android {
    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    namespace = "com.arindom.cosmonaut"
    compileSdk = libs.versions.compileSdk.get().toInt()
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = libs.versions.minSdk.get().toInt()
        targetSdk = libs.versions.targetSdk.get().toInt()
    }
}
```

`

Im trying multi-module design inside shared code and expecting that it should generate the code for the respective platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `export` methods to get submodules implementation in your shared library. Please take a look at [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-build-native-binaries.html#export-dependencies-to-binaries).

In your `kmm/shared/build.gradle.kts` in `framework` section add

```kotlin
export(project(":kmm:features:spaceXLaunches"))
export(project(":kmm:core:common"))
```

It should look like this:

```kotlin
...

kotlin {
    android()
    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach {
        it.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "shared"
            export(project(":kmm:features:spaceXLaunches"))
            export(project(":kmm:core:common"))
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                ...
                api(project(":kmm:features:spaceXLaunches"))
                api(project(":kmm:core:common"))
                ...
            }
        }

...
```